# Запрос на каждую ссылку из txt файла

Tags: python, парсер, requests, текст

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на каждую ссылку из txt файла сделать запрос и вернуть html с каждого адреса.
Вот пример кода.

```
def data():
    f = open('links.txt', 'r')
    url_list = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    

    # print(links)
    s = requests.Session()
      
    for url in url_list():
        response = s.get(url=url, headers=headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

        article = soup.find('div', class_ = 'page-title').find_next('h1').get_text()
```

Comment: Если что, каждая ссылка на новой строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def data():
    links = []
    with open('links.txt', encoding='utf8') as file:
        while True:
            line = file.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            line = line.replace('\n', '')
            links.append(line)

    with requests.Session() as se:
        for link in links:
            resp = se.get(link)

            ...


data()
```